# php - can't find file with underscores

Tags: php

I don't know why but php still can't find file with underscores

```
Pool::registerPacket(DATA_PACKET_6::$ID, DATA_PACKET_6::class);
```

This is my current code and it just don't find file
But when I try find file without underscore like this:

```
 Pool::registerPacket(OpenConnectionReply1::$ID, OpenConnectionReply1::class);
```

Then everything works
I'm using PHP 7.2
How I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is with the class loader you are using - for example, PSR-0 autoloaders are processing underscores in class name as directory delimiters (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).

Please provide your composer.json (if you are using composer) and complete namespace and path for the classes you are using.